# Dynamically finding the destination of the project

Tags: java

I can use:

getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath());

To dynamically get the path of the Class files in my project.

But I need to get the path dynamically for the home directory of the project.  I can't do this statically, like this:

File file = new File("C:\Users\etc...");

Because the destination of the project can change from one computer to the next.  I need to call a file in the project's home directory.  How do I do that dynamically.  It would be similar to how I did it in the beginning of this question, but it can not be just for Classes.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not just create the path string for your class using your earlier strategy and then use that as input to File constructor?

Comment: The home directory of your project doesn't exist at runtime. Do you mean the installation directory? Say of a web-app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "java project" in Java. If you know where your class files are in relationship to whatever directory you're trying to locate, you can use the path you obtained in your first example:

```
Url classUrl = ...
File resourcePath = new File(classUrl.toUri());
File rootDir = resourcePath.getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile();
```

or

```
File rootDir = new File(resourcePath.getPath() + 
    "/../../../".replace("/", File.separatorChar));
```

Of course, this will only work as long as the files are actually on the file system; if they're in a jar, you'd need to locate the jar file instead.

But this is usually not something you want to do. It's a better practice to configure a sandbox for your application by passing them to your application as command-line arguments or environment variables. In some cases, it's also useful to use the pre-defined System properties such as `user.home`, `user.dir`, and `java.io.tmpdir`.

Comment: The reason for this, I am creating a java swing GUI and inside this project it will have a HelpMaker project (which is a .chm file... ex: HelpMaker.chm ) it will need to point to.  I am trying to figure out a way for this to work after the java swing project is cleaned & Built, it will be able to point to this file successfully.  Can you think of a better way to do this?

Comment: Again, there's no such notion as "a project" in Java. It sounds like a specific IDE terminology. If you're only trying to access a specific file, you can make sure it's on the classpath and refer to it explicitly using the ClassLoader.getResource() method just as you described previously.